# List of library versions in stable releases

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

I am developping a free software, and this software is using a shared library from the system.

Unfortunately, the original author of the library decided to change the API at one point in time, so now I have to maintain two branches of the software.

To make a decision, if maintaining both branches is still justified, I would like to have a list of versions of the library in different OS releases and distributions. Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [whohas](http://www.philippwesche.org/200811/whohas/intro.html), which is a tool that does what I was looking for.